# On a suggested edit page the links to other "recent decisions" are broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits

If I try to follow a link from one suggested edit to another recent decision by the same reviewer, the links are invalid.

*Firefox 3.6.14, Win 7 Pro x64*

---

Here's an example screenshot taken on https://superuser.com/suggested-edits/747

[image: Showing "recent decisions" list of suggested edits having incorrect links]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interestingly, Chrome rewrites the link to work, substituting backslashes with forward slashes – but of course that doesn't make it better (and still misses an "s"). Fixed in the next build, thanks!